# Windows Script Host Error 800A03EA on Express.js code

Tags: javascript, express, syntax

I am learning JavaScript development and the book I'm following (JavaScript Everywhere) tells me run this code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'));
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on port 4000!'));
```

I understand what this code is supposed to do but when I try to run it using src/index.js in the terminal, it always gives me this error:
[Syntax Error 800A03EA Microsoft JScript compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FwyL.png)

I have tried all fixes I found on the internet but I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that this isn't regular JS syntax, it's Express JS and somehow Express JS is not enabled? I've checked the basics including:

1. node --version (returns v12.14.0)
2. npm --version (returns 6.13.4)
3. npm install express --save just in case there was some problem with ExpressJS API

Windows 10 Laptop, using VSCode. Please ask for any information you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run it using `node src/index.js`.

By using just `src/index.js` you are using the default handler for JS files on Windows which is Windows Script Host (and not Node.js).

Comment: Is it possible to register node as the default handler for JS files?

Comment: I specified a custom command name in package.json bin field, and ran npm link. However running my custom command gives me the same JScript compilation error

Answer (score 0):

***The solution apply for those who are facing Windows script Error code like 800A03EA. For those, who are unable to open js file and facing error like Windows Script Host.***

I was stuck with the same problem for couple of days while working on react.

We have three methods of solving this problem:

**Method 1:**
Check your computer for viruses and remove them using various method like download MSERT.exe from Microsoft.

**Method 2:**
Open command prompt as administrator and type following 2 commands:

> regsvr32 jscript.dll and press ENTER.
>
> regsvr32 vbscript.dll and press ENTER.

**Method 3:**
Type internet option on search bar and select it.
Open advance gtab from it and go to security section.
Make sure all of the below ones are selected:

> Use SSL 3.0
>
> Use TLS 1.0
>
> Use TLS 1.1
>
> Use TLS 1.2

**Method 4:**

The workaround that must work 100% but as you know it might be helpful for all, as it only open file do not confuse read the following lines
So simply left click on file and edit and open it.
It will open in notepad and now from here you can transfer your data or use it.

Thanks me later for this detail answer. Now just rock the world!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file name isn't "Node.js", just try to rename it in like "randomname.js"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).